# Java Terminology/Lingo

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I primarily come from a PHP background but I have been asked to develop a website using the Java platform.  I have been exposed to some terminology that I don't quite yet understand and I was hoping that anybody with Java familiarity could let me know in basic terms what it means/is used for.  Or if you could tell me its equivalency in the PHP world that would be great too.  The words are:

1. Spring
2. Struts
3. JavaBeans
4. EJB
5. JMS
6. Servlet

Thanks!

Comment: Showing a minimal effort on your side (e.g., wikipedia) would not harm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all most of them are Technologies that have been wrapped up around Java EE architecture. First of all do you understand what MVC stands for. MVC is Model-View-Controller pattern. It is a design principle that lets you separate your concerns easily. There are couple of PHP frameworks that follow MVC pattern. Eg:- [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/)

**Spring**

Spring is an MVC aritecture but beware it's not just for MVC... Spring has loads of uses. If you have used frameworks related to PHP such as Zend or CakePHP you could say that Spring is similar to them. You can checkout the [Spring features](http://www.springsource.org/features).

**Struts**

Struts is a Front End controller. It takes all the requests and map them to their relevant actions. Here is a part from Apache Struts website

> One way to separate concerns in a software application is to use a
>   Model-View-Controller (MVC) architecture. The Model represents the
>   business or database code, the View represents the page design code,
>   and the Controller represents the navigational code. The Struts
>   framework is designed to help developers create web applications that
>   utilize a MVC architecture.

Here are the basic components of Struts.

1. A "request" handler provided by the application developer that is
   mapped to a standard URI.
2. A "response" handler that transfers control to another resource
   which completes the response.
3. A tag library that helps developers create interactive form-based
   applications with server pages.

PHP equivalent for this should probably be the Routes module in a PHP framework. Some helpful sources to easily get started with Struts -

[Struts for dummies](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/what-is-jakarta-struts.html)

**JavaBeans**

1. Java beans are rather simple. They follow a standard. Here are the
   followed conventions - The class must have a public default
   constructor (no-argument). This allows easy instantiation within
   editing and activation frameworks.
2. The class properties must be accessible using get, set, is (used for
   boolean properties instead of get) and other methods (so-called
   accessor methods and mutator methods), following a standard naming
   convention. This allows easy automated inspection and updating of
   bean state within frameworks, many of which include custom editors
   for various types of properties. Setters must receive only one
   argument.
3. The class should be serializable. It allows applications and
   frameworks to reliably save, store, and restore the bean's state in
   a fashion independent of the VM and of the platform.

If you found above explanations harder to understand that's fine since Java Beans can be explained by an example simply.

```
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable{
 private String name;
 private Integer id;
 public Student(){}

 public void setName(String name){
  this.name=name;
 }
 public String getName(){
  return this.name;
 }
 public void setId(Integer id){
  this.id=id;
 }
public Integer getId(){
 return this.id;
 }
}
```

More helpful sources from - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans). Probably this is a PHP class.

**EJB**

EJB - Enterprise Java Beans. This probably doesn't have a PHP alternative. EJB is bit complex. It's kinda of like a mega bean that has business logic around it. Best place to find more is [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans) -

**JMS**

JMS stands for Java Messaging Service. JMS provides communication in between Java applications. JMS is a technology and there are many provider implementations of it. Best I heard of happens to be [HornetQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HornetQ). Beware that I haven't used it. There is no PHP counter part as I know.

**Servlet**

Servlet is what takes the request and provides controller logic. Servlet routes the files back again to a JSP - which a Java Server page. This can be your PHP frameworks controller code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  And yes I do know MVC :)

Answer (score 1):

Many Java enterprise technologies have been standardized in the [Java Platform, Enterprise Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html). Even those that aren't part of the standard are often related to it in some way, for instance because they implement parts of Java EE, or attempt to improve on (replace) parts of it. Therefore, the standard is a good resource to get an overview over what libraries exist and what they do. Admittedly those specification documents make for rather dry reading, so Oracle has provided a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/), too.

Ok, that should cover the standard technologies (in your list: JavaBeans, EJB, JMS, Servlet).

Spring is actually a portfolio of libraries. You are probably looking for the Spring dependency injection container (which is a replacement for EJB / CDI), but Spring also offers a web framework and many other things.

Struts is a web application framework, replacing Java EE JSP.